# Content type from Apache Rewrite module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try to pass content type to my script by the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /* /usr/lib/cgi-bin/leecher/leecher.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}&q=%{QUERY_STRING}&ct=%{HTTP:Content-Type}
```

ct parameters gets nothing

What do you I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header is set on the responses from the server to the client, or sent with a `POST` request. AFAIK, with a `GET` there is no `Content-Type` header sent. That's why your ct param is empty.

As you use php, you already have all of those parameters in the `$_SERVER` array... could be easier than creating new query strings.